# How to realize nested parallel in R on windows platform

Tags: windows, r, parallel-processing, scientific-computing

I try to use `parApply()` in parallel package in R.

```
 cl <- makeCluster(16)
 cl.boot <-makeCluster(8)
```

In my programme, I call `t(parApply(cl,rv,1,sim.one.test))` first. In function `sim.one.test`,a call a function `boot()`. And in `boot()`, I use

```
 bs.resample <- t(parApply(cl.boot,rv.boot,1,function(x) bs.mle(n1,n2,x,s,t1,t2,m,theta)))
```

Simply, the outer function is `sim.one.test()` and inner one is `bs.mle()`. 
The error information is `invalid connection`. I guess this is because nested parallel is not supported. From another [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413188/can-i-nest-parallelparlapply) on stackoverflow, it is suggested I should use `mcapply()` which only can be applied on Linux but I run the programme on Windows platform. Is there any solution for nested parallel computing on Windows platform? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you need nested parallelization? That will just increase your parallelization overhead (if it works at all, which I doubt). Conceptually, it's by far better to only parallelize the outer loop (provided it contains enough iterations and is more or less load-balanced).

However, you could use [nested `foreach` loops](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf) with a parallel backend. That would convert your nested loops into one loop before sending it to the workers.