# R can't find 'parApply()' function after loading 'parallel' package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply

I want to make my apply() function run parallel. I have loaded the parallel package and made a cluster. Then i have just changed the apply() function to the parApply() function. Unfortunately R doesn't seem to see the function parApply().
Help would be very appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Jakub

My initial code:

- TRAITS and SNP are matrices
- the calling of apply() worked with no errors

```
library(parallel)
system.file(package='parallel')
detectCores()

copies_of_r <- 7

cl <- makeCluster(copies_of_r)

parApply(cl ,TRAITS,2,function(x) parApply(cl, SNP, 2, function(y) summary(lm(x~y))$coefficients[2,4]))
```

---

I got this:

```
> library(parallel)
> system.file(package='parallel')
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/library/parallel"
> detectCores()
[1] 8
> 
> copies_of_r <- 7
> 
> cl <- makeCluster(copies_of_r)
> 
> parApply(cl ,TRAITS,2,function(x) parApply(cl, SNP, 2, function(y) summary(lm(x~y))$coefficients[2,4]))
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  7 nodes produced errors; first error: nie udało się znaleźć funkcji* 'parApply'`
```

---

- "nie udało się znaleźć funkcji" == "failed to find funtion"

---

I also tried to call parApply() in this way:

```
parallel:: parApply(cl ,TRAITS,2,function(x) parApply(cl, SNP, 2, function(y) summary(lm(x~y))$coefficients[2,4]))
```

but I got the same result as before.

I also tried:

```
getAnywhere(parApply)
```

And suprisingly, R seems to see the function parApply() but has a problem, when I try to call it.

```
A single object matching ‘parApply’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:parallel
  namespace:parallel
with value

(...)
```

Comment: What do you get if you run `parallel::parApply()` - no arguments?  What about `parallel::parApply` to view the source?

Comment: One possible candidate is that you're trying to call parApply() within a parApply() call - see discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413188/can-i-nest-parallelparlapply

Comment: As Paul says, you're calling `parApply()` in the parallel workers running in the background. Since you haven't attached the **parallel** package in those workers, they have no idea about that function.  You only attached **parallel** in the main R session.

Comment: More importantly, you rarely want to do nested parallelization as you attempt. It risks overloading your machine.  Also, you cannot pass one cluster object (here `cl`) down to parallel workers; such objects only work in the R session they're created in.